# Embed Youtube Video To Facebook And Play At Specific Timecode

Tags: facebook, video, parameters, youtube, embed

I have a :30 YouTube video that I want to embed onto Facebook and start playback at :16.

I thought this would be easy enough changing the parameters in the URL for share, or the URL in the embed code. But when I post this on Facebook, even though the URL's will link to YouTube and play at the correct :16 mark, they always start from :00 when playback is initiated inside Facebook.

Does Facebook strip all of the URL parameters for embeded YouTube videos? Is there a work-around?

I've tried:

```
https://youtu.be/yR8fp-XzJIo?t=16s
```

And I've tried:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://youtu.be/yR8fp-XzJIo?t=16s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And I've tried:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://youtu.be/yR8fp-XzJIo?start=16&end=38" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Nothing seems to work. I have an idea that depends on this functionality, so I'd love some help if anyone knows a work-around or even a reason. Thanks so much, crew!

Answer (score 6):

Facebook behaved itself with a URL in this form:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgGlbVtd7wc&t=2m53s

Comment: Perfect! It really works! Thanks. There's some differences in the link that makes it work.

Answer (score 4):

While I cannot think of a workaround, I think the reason why the video always starts from :00 is how the Facebook scraper works to fetch meta data for Open Graph objects. If you pop your url into the [URL debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) you will see that `og:url` points to the [actual url](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yR8fp-XzJIo) of the video. The scraper treats this as a redirect and takes data from there.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yR8fp-XzJIo">
```

Hence, when you share the video on your wall, the actual meta data for the video is taken from the site pointed to by the `og:url` tag which is the actual video without the `t` parameter that sets the playback start time.

Comment: Ahhh. It appears you are correct. Thank you so much for the help! I know it used to work, as I can see examples posted in November that work, but it looks like that's no more. Vielen dank!

Answer (score 0):

Embedded videos don't work. If you want to post a video starting at a specific position, click "Remove Preview" and they'll have to click the link.

Comment: Great simple suggestion I hadn't thought about. Solved the problem for me.

Comment: You're wrokg. It really works inside facebook. See the user3673 answer.